# Meet core dump when after _eXosip_release_terminated_calls

Tags: sip, exosip

I use exosip 5.2.0，and send register via eXosip_register_send_register.
I have more than one number should be registed, so there will be twice or more register request to be send.

however, I always meet core dump after register success for a while and the stack info is like below:

```
#0  osip_list_get_first (li=li@entry=0x11fc500, iterator=iterator@entry=0x7f2ff767bd30) at osip_list.c:211
#1  0x00007f2ffaef4ac0 in _eXosip_release_terminated_calls (excontext=excontext@entry=0x11fc240) at udp.c:2372
#2  0x00007f2ffaee29f1 in eXosip_execute (excontext=excontext@entry=0x11fc240) at eXconf.c:960
#3  0x00007f2ffaee2db8 in _eXosip_thread (arg=0x11fc240) at eXconf.c:1416
#4  0x00007f2ff9f4dea5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f2ff91d78dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I guess it may be related to transaction management becuase it happens on the line:

```
tr = (osip_transaction_t *) osip_list_get_first(&excontext->j_transactions, &it);
```

Comment: I'm the author of exosip and may help with more info. May be you can share code that I could compile and run. (may be via email if too large)

Comment: Hi @AymericM，nice to see you agian:-)! Could you please give me your email address?

Comment: Here is it: amoizard_at_gmail.com

Comment: thx, I have sent email to your address:-)

Comment: With the help of AymericM, I have fix this problem. It was caused by missing usage of  eXosip_lock and eXosip_unlock when I call exosip API with access to the exosip context.